# Configure ActiveMQ with MySQL

Tags: mysql, activemq-classic

I need to setup ActiveMQ with MySQL which i follow this article
http://note19.com/2007/06/23/configure-activemq-with-mysql/

I found if i have below config. MQ can't start

```
 <bean id="mysql-ds"
       class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
       destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/activemq?relaxAutoCommit=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
  </bean>
```

Below is the error

> 2012-05-25 18:40:46,565 | ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource
>   [activemq.xml], reason: Line 109 in XML document from class path
>   resource [activemq.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 109; columnNumber: 40;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'bean'. One of
>   '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":adminView,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":brokerContext,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":consumerSystemUsage,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinationFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinationInterceptors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinationPolicy,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinations,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":ioExceptionHandler,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":jmsBridgeConnectors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":managementContext,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":messageAuthorizationPolicy,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":networkConnectorURIs,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":networkConnectors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":persistenceAdapter,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":persistenceFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":persistenceTaskRunnerFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":plugins,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":producerSystemUsage,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":proxyConnectors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":regionBroker,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":services,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":shutdownHooks,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":sslContext,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":systemUsage,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":taskRunnerFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":tempDataStore,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":transportConnectorURIs,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":transportConnectors,
>   WC[##other:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"]}' is expected. |
>   org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory | main
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 109 in XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 109; columnNumber: 40; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'bean'. One of
>   '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":adminView,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":brokerContext,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":consumerSystemUsage,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinationFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinationInterceptors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinationPolicy,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":destinations,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":ioExceptionHandler,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":jmsBridgeConnectors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":managementContext,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":messageAuthorizationPolicy,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":networkConnectorURIs,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":networkConnectors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":persistenceAdapter,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":persistenceFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":persistenceTaskRunnerFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":plugins,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":producerSystemUsage,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":proxyConnectors,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":regionBroker,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":services,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":shutdownHooks,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":sslContext,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":systemUsage,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":taskRunnerFactory,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":tempDataStore,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":transportConnectorURIs,
>   "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":transportConnectors,
>   WC[##other:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"]}' is expected.

ref:

1. mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
2. activemq Ver 5.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are providing  definition within the broker tag. Please create datasource bean outside the broker. Please refer this [link](http://jason-sherman.blogspot.in/2012/02/activemq-jdbc-master-slave-with-mysql.html).

Answer (score 1):

The example on the referenced blog is out of date.  The persistence element should be defined as:

```
    <persistenceFactory>
        <journalPersistenceAdapterFactory 
            journalLogFiles="5" 
            dataDirectory="${basedir}/activemq-data" 
            dataSource="#mysql-ds"/>
    </persistenceFactory>
```

That should fix the issue.

Regards,
Scott ES